# Straight lines and text jagged after updating

Tags: java, graphics

I was away from my project for 6 months, coming back to it I upgraded to Eclipse 2020.12 which installs/uses the open java version 15. I did a lot of programming before noting this issues and comparing it to prior build but here's the issue...

My STRAIGHT lines and text are a lot more jagged than they used to be. I'm not sure how to show an image here that isn't online anymore, but a straight line has thicker and thinner areas to it, and text is really jagged.

Any thoughts? Is it the open JDK? I plan on distributing and don't want to use the commercial version and Eclipse no longer supports release 8 it says.

Thanks!

```
        super.paintComponent(g);     
        String[] splitData = null;                          // holds string split into pieces   
        boolean success = false;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform transform = g2.getTransform();      // save current transform values
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));                // set width of stroke
        String rgb = props.getProperty(CFG.colorBack.toString());   // set backcolor of plot
        thisControl.setBackground(process.getColor(rgb));
        
        g.drawLine(10, 30, 500, 30);
        Font font = new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("test", 300, 50);
```

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Be consistent with the graphics object you use to do the painting. If you are going to create a g2 variable, then use that for the painting.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try, after some testing it appears due to the fact I'm using buffered images, and I think there's an issue with the sizing maybe? Once I remove the buffering, it seems perfect. I'll try to see if I can reproduce with a simplified application.